# ResultSet is closed. Why?

Tags: java, sqlite, resultset

I've got a small problem. I launch my application and after launching a query and comparing `rs == null` I get error `ResultSet is closed`.

Here is the code:

```
error_code = NO_ERROR;
    try
    {
        ArrayList <Harmonogram> al = new ArrayList <Harmonogram> ();
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(myQuery);
        if (rs == null)
        {
            return null;
        }else{
            Harmonogram harm = new Harmonogram(rs.getLong(1), rs.getInt(2), rs.getInt(3), rs.getInt(4), rs.getLong(5), rs.getString(6));
```

After this I get a `SQLException` telling me: `ResultSet is closed`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using incorrect method of checking whether `ResultSet` has any data.

Instead of

```
if ( rs == null )
{
    return null;
}
```

use

```
if ( ! rs.next( ) )
{
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29) for `PreparedStatement.executeQuery()` says:

> *"Returns: a ResultSet object that contains the data produced by the query; **never null**"*

The correct way to test for an empty `ResultSet` is to call `ResultSet.hasNext()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd recommend that you write it:

```
public class HarmonogramDaoImpl implements HarmonogramDao {

    private static final String FIND_ALL_SQL = "SELECT * FROM HARMONOGRAM ";

    // inject this with either a constructor or setter
    private Connection connection;



    public List<Harmonogram> findAllHarmonograms() throws SQLException {
        List<Harmonogram> harmonograms = new ArrayList<Harmonogram>();

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            ps = this.connection.prepareStatement(FIND_ALL_SQL);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.hasNext()) {
                Harmonogram harm = new Harmonogram(rs.getLong(1), rs.getInt(2), rs.getInt(3),      rs.getInt(4), rs.getLong(5), rs.getString(6));            
                harmonograms.add(harm);
            }
        } finally {
            close(rs);
            close(ps);
        }        
        return harmonograms;
    }
}
```

There are a few things left for you to do or guess, but this is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like

```
error_code = NO_ERROR;
try
{
    ArrayList <Harmonogram> al = new ArrayList <Harmonogram> ();
    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(myQuery);
    if (rs.next()){
       Harmonogram harm = new Harmonogram(rs.getLong(1), rs.getInt(2), rs.getInt(3),      rs.getInt(4), rs.getLong(5), rs.getString(6));
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}Catch...
```

Or even `while(rs.next())` if you're trying to loop over the resultSet (get all the records pulled from the database)